# ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, docker-compose

I'm new to kobotoolbox. I m trying to setup kobo on my server env. I followed bellow process

1. Very first I started with Installation steps as specified in https://github.com/kobotoolbox/kobo-docker.
   Here in 6th point they have mention to fill all mandatory variables. 
   So from where I would get value for "mandatory variable" like DJANGO_SECRET_KEY and all ?
   So without modifying any value of "envfile.server.txt" proceed further step.
2. Then tried to hit command -- sudo docker run kobotoolbox/kobocat -- getting error 
   "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty"

where should I specify secret key and from where I would get all mandatory value?
m missing any step, please guide

Answer (score 0):

## You can get DJANGO_SECRET_KEY from online django key generator.

After you copy docker-compose-yml content to docker-compose.yml you must edit envfile.txt

sample envfile.txt

```
    HOST_ADDRESS= 172.17.0.1
    ENKETO_API_TOKEN= '$#=#i3l2fxe)y1*gwpq&rj=  (@73881una=!+7vwv_q&rp6k362'
    DJANGO_SECRET_KEY= '$#=#i3l2fxe)y1*gwpq&rj=(@73881una=!+7vwv_q&rp6k362'
    KOBO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME= 'admin'
    KOBO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD= 'admin'
    KPI_PUBLIC_PORT=8000
    KOBOCAT_PUBLIC_PORT=8001
    ENKETO_EXPRESS_PUBLIC_PORT=8005
```

## use docker-compose up to run kobotoolbox